# In Function Interface declaration, how to pass another Function Interface as argument?

Tags: lambda, java-8, interface, functional-interface

I want to do something like this -

```
final Function<Function<Integer, Integer>, Integer> function = (//appropriate syntax)
```

Is it possible to do so? If yes, what will be the correct syntax?

Comment: Seems OK? Is there an issue?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the `//appropriate syntax` part, I am getting error in IDE

Comment: `x -> 1` for example. You still need to take one parameter and return one. Or if you want to call the passed in function and supply `1` as an argument `x -> x.apply(1)`.

Comment: For example in `Function<Integer, Integer> function1 = num -> num + 1` can be done, but if I try `Function<Function<Integer, Integer> Integer> function2 = (num -> num + 1) -> num + 2`  I can't do it

Comment: `Function<Function<Integer, Integer> Integer>` means that *the parameter expected* is a function. What you seem to be trying to define is not that. I'm not even sure what it should be. What is your goal here? What are you trying to achieve? I suspect `Function<Function<Integer, Integer> Integer>` is not the correct type.

Comment: I am trying to pass `function1`  `Function<T, R>`  into `function2`  ` Function<T, R>`  where `T ` in  `function2`  is `function1`.

Comment: Then see [Yassin Hajaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66223246/). You don't need to define `num -> num + 1` in the function that takes another function. You'll be passing it in as a parameter, so you'd be calling `function.apply(num -> num + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it's totally possible, here is an example of how to implement it

```
int input = 2;
Function<Integer, Integer> times10Function = i -> i * 10;
Function<Function<Integer, Integer>, Integer> minus10Function = func -> func.apply(input) - 10;

Integer result = minus10Function.apply(times10Function);
System.out.println(result); // 10
```

The fact you can't do `(i -> i + 10) -> ...` is the same reason you can't use constants in methods signatures, these are placeholders, not actual implementations and they're thus piloted by the invoker

Comment: "you can't use constants in methods signatures, these are placeholders, not actual implementations and they're thus piloted by the invoker" - please explain

Comment: @VLAZ please explain the above quoted part

Comment: @PayelSenapati simply put, don't try to put a lambda where a parameter is expected. e.g. `x -> x + 1` is a lambda function and the parameter is `x`. It's incorrect to try and do `y -> y + 2` in its place.

Comment: @VLAZ replacing `input` in `func.apply(input) - 10` by 2 seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: And the variant without boxing overhead: `IntUnaryOperator times10Function = i -> i * 10; ToIntFunction<IntUnaryOperator> minus10Function = func -> func.applyAsInt(2) - 10; int result = minus10Function.applyAsInt(times10Function);`

Comment: Thanks @holger thats true indeed. once I get a grip on my pc I'll add this

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Yassin Hajaj is perfect. However, I came up with an even better example for clearer understanding -

```
        final int base1 = 3;
        final int base2 = 5;
        final int index = 2;

        final Function<BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer >, Function<Integer, Integer>> power = func ->
                myIndex -> {
            int result = 1;
            int base = func.apply(base1, base2);
            for (int i = 1; i <= myIndex; i++) {
                result *= base;
            }
            return result;
        };

        final BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> addition = (num1, num2) -> num1 + num2;

        final int result = power.apply(addition).apply(index);

        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Output -

```
Result: 64
```

Here, there are two functions.

`addition` function's job is to define addition of two numbers.

`power` function takes `addition` function as argument, performs the addition of `base1` and `base2` to get the `base`. As a second argument `power` takes the `index` and then performs the power operation of base to the power index and returns the result.